# How to write where condition in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table Named CLASS and subject

```
select id,
       name,
       (select subjectName from Subject where subjectId = t.subId) subjectName,
       subId 
from class t;

select subjectId, subjectName 
from Subject;
```

I need to write a where condition to that like this against subject name

```
select id,
       name,
       (select subjectName from Subject where subjectId = t.subId) subjectName,
       subId 
from class t
where subjectName like '%ng%';
```

But this is not working how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a join instead of a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT id, name, subjectName, subId 
FROM   class t
JOIN   subject s ON s.subjectID = t.subId AND subjectName like '%ng%';
```

Comment: Okay if it is like thisI have a master table which contains key and value column.
select key,value from master;

I have another table called class,

select id,Name, (Select value from master where key=t.subId)SubjectName, (select value from master where key=t.teacherId)teacherName from table class t

How to write a where condition to this

select id,Name, (Select value from master where key=t.subId)SubjectName, (select value from master where key=t.teacherId)teacherName from table class t where SubjectName like '%en%'; if multiple values are being taken i cant do join know